# C to Delphi very short

Tags: delphi

```
StructBox_s *pStructBox; // -> pStructBox: ^StructBox_s
int value = pStructBox[11].value; // ???
```

Can't convert to Delphi code.
"pSturctBox[11].value" <-

Comment: You've posted two lines of code totally out of context, with no explanation of what the data types are and not a bit of Delphi code to show your efforts to convert. We can't help based on information you've not provided. Please read [mre] and [ask], and then [edit] your question. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `pStructBox: ^StructBox_s` would be the Delphi equivalent of `StructBox_s *pStructBox;` in C/C++. It is common practice to use a type alias to make the `^` syntax easier to work with.

What the C/C++ code is doing is treating the pointer as the address of an array of `StructBox_s` instances, accessing the `value` member of the 11th element of that array.  The snippet you have shown does not show how that pointer is being assigned that array address. It could be assigned the address of a local variable, a global variable, a class member, a dynamic array, there are many different ways. But the result of applying the `[]` operator on the pointer is the same - accessing a `StructBox_s` instance that is `11 * sizeof(StructBox_s)` bytes from the address that the pointer is pointing at.

In Delphi, in order to index into a typed pointer the same way the C/C++ code is doing, you can enable the [`{$POINTERMATH}`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Pointer_Math_(Delphi)) directive in scope of the pointer being indexed.

You can either enable the directive when declaring the *type* that is used for the pointer, eg:

```pascal
type
  {$POINTERMATH ON}
  PStructBox_s = ^StructBox_s;
  StructBox_s = record
    ...
    value: Integer;
    ...
  end;
  
...

var
  pStructBox: PStructBox_s;
  value: Integer;
begin
  ...
  pStructBox := ...; // <-- set to the address of some array of 12+ StructBox_s instances in memory...
  value := pStructBox[11].value;
  ...
end;
```

Or, enable the directive within the code that is doing the actual indexing:

```pascal
type
  PStructBox_s = ^StructBox_s;
  StructBox_s = record
    ...
    value: Integer;
    ...
  end;
  
...

{$POINTERMATH ON}
var
  pStructBox: PStructBox_s;
  value: Integer;
begin
  ...
  pStructBox := ...; // <-- set to the address of some array of 12+ StructBox_s instances in memory...
  value := pStructBox[11].value;
  ...
end;
```

That being said, if you are using an older version of Delphi that doesn't have the `{$POINTERMATH}` directive, the same result can be accomplished by manually incrementing the pointer to the desired offset, eg:

```pascal
type
  PStructBox_s = ^StructBox_s;
  StructBox_s = record
    ...
    value: Integer;
    ...
  end;
  
...

var
  pStructBox, pElem: PStructBox_s;
  value: Integer;
begin
  ...
  pStructBox := ...; // <-- set to the address of some array of 12+ StructBox_s instances in memory...
  pElem := pStructBox;
  Inc(pElem, 11);
  value := pElem^.value;
  ...
end;
```

Comment: Am I right that you could also disable range checking, and use `type TAStructBox_s = array [0..0] of StructBox_s; var p:TAStructBox_S; begin ... value:=p[11].value;` ?

Comment: @StijnSanders that does not do the same thing that the C/C++ code is doing. And just because the Delphi compiler won't complain about going out of bounds, the code would nonetheless still be accessing out of bounds into surrounding memory.